# Use of obtain produces a fixed type variable warning

Tags: isabelle

A [question is posed on the IsaUserList](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fa.isabelle/JMS05f9Z_EY) on how to prove this `lemma`:

```
lemma "dom (SOME b. dom b = A) = A"
```

As a first response, P.Lammich says that `obtain` needs to be used:

```
You have to show that there is such a beast b, ie,   
proof -
  obtain b where "dom b = A" ...
  thus ?thesis
sledgehammer (*Should find a proof now, using the rules for SOME, probably SomeI*)
```

Here, I have one main question, one secondary question, and I wonder about some differences between what P.Lammich says to do, some things M.Eberl does, and the results that I got.

- **Q1:** I get the warning `Introduced fixed type variable(s): 'c in "b__"` at my use of `obtain`, and at the use of the `by` statement that proves the `obtain`. Can I get rid of this warning?
- **Q2:** Is there a command of three dots, `...`? I assume it means, "Your proof goes here." However, it sometimes sounds like the writer is also saying, "...because, after all, the proof is really simple here." I also know that there is the command `.` for `by this`, and `..` for `by rule`. Additionally, I entertain the idea that `...` is commonly known to be some simple proof statement which I'm supposed to know, but don't.

The following source will show the warning. It could be I'm supposed to `fix` something. The source also shows how I had to help `sledgehammer`, which is that I had to put an exists statement it.

I leave the error in that's due to the schematic variable, in case anyone is interested in that.

```
(* I HELP SLEDGEHAMMER with an exists statement. I can delete the exists 
   statement after the `metis` proof is found.
     The `?'c1` below causes an error, but `by` still proves the goal.
*)
lemma "dom (SOME b. dom b = A) = A"
proof-
have "? x. x = (SOME b. dom b = A)"
  by(simp)
  from this 
obtain b where ob1: "dom b = A"
  (*WARNING: Orange squiggly under `obtain`. Message: Introduced fixed type 
    variable(s): 'c in "b__".*)
  by(metis (full_types) dom_const dom_restrict inf_top_left)
thus ?thesis
  using[[show_types]]
  (*Because of `show_types`, a schematic type variable `?'c1` will be part
    of the proof command that `sledgehammer` provides in the output panel.*)
  (*sledgehammer[minimize=smart,preplay_timeout=10,timeout=60,verbose=true,
    isar_proofs=smart,provers="z3  spass remote_vampire"]*)  
  by(metis (lifting, full_types)
    `!!thesis::bool.(!!b::'a => ?'c1 option. dom b = (A::'a set) ==> thesis) 
      ==> thesis` 
    someI_ex)  
  (*ERROR: Illegal schematic type variable: ?'c1::type.
    To get rid of the error, delete `?`, or use `ob1` as the fact.*)
qed
```

My Q1 and Q2 are related to what's above. As part of my wonderings, there is the issue of getting an error because of the schematic variable. I may report that as bug-type issue.

In his IsaUserList response, M.Eberl says that he got the following `sledgehammer` proof for the `obtain`. He says the proof is slow, and it is. It's about 2 seconds for me.

```
by(metis (lifting, full_types) 
        dom_const dom_restrict inf_top.left_neutral someI_ex)
```

The proof that `sledgehammer` found for me above for `thus ?thesis` is only 4ms.

Comment: There is no command called "..." There are ".", which, if I recall correctly, is more or less the same as "by assumption" and "..", which is more or less the same as "by rule". However, in Isar proofs, "..." can be used as an abbreviation for some previous term; what it is exactly depends on the context, the details can probably be found in some tutorial. I think in this context, Peter just meant "Put in your proof here". In fact, I wouldn't use "obtain" anyway here, just show the statement holds for some witness and go on from there.

Comment: @manuel, thanks. In looking for a way to get a witness another way, I stumbled on how to get rid of the warning. In my answer, I show two proofs, one based on `def` and another with `fix/assumes` in place of `def`. If you understand the mystery of the "Failed to refine any pending goal", please comment.

Comment: @manuel, I found some info on the list that partially explains how `def` and `fixes/assumes` are different, which allowed me to get rid of the "Failed to refine..." in an acceptable way, by using brackets. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to Q1**

Because of M.Eberl's comment, I made a respectable effort to figure out how to get a witness without using `obtain`. In the process, I answered my main question.

I got rid of the warning about introducing `'c` as a type variable by using `b :: "'a => 'b option"`, instead of `b`, as shown here:

```
lemma "dom (SOME b. dom b = A) = A"
proof-
obtain b :: "'a => 'b option" where "dom (b) = A"
  by(metis (full_types) dom_const dom_restrict inf_top_left)
thus ?thesis
  by(metis (lifting, full_types) exE_some)
qed
```

**Answer to Q2**

(Update 140119) I finally found Isar syntax for `...`, on [page 6 of isar-ref.pdf](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013-2/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/isar-ref.pdf).

> `term ...` -- the argument of the last explicitly stated result (for infix application this is the right-hand side)

The string `...` is not exactly a friendly search string. Finding the meaning was a result of starting to look through chapter 1. I now see that chapters 1, 2, and 6 of `isar-ref.pdf` are key chapters for getting some help on how to use Isar to do proofs. (End update.)

**Concerning an error due to using `fix/assume` as an alternate to `obtain`**

Now, I return back to M.Eberl telling me I shouldn't use `obtain`, which happened to be beneficial. But it brings up that it's a major effort to try to figure out how to use the language to make the PIDE happy. The last source I show below is another example of what a hassle it is to learn how to make the PIDE happy. To a large extent, it's just using examples to try and figure out the right combination of syntax and commands.

P.Lammich says to use `obtain` in his answer. I also looked up the use of `obtain` in [prog-prove.pdf page 42](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013-2/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/prog-prove.pdf), which discusses it in connection with the use of a witness.

I read a few other things, and I thought it was all telling me that `obtain` is crucial to fixing a variable or constant with certain properties.

Anyway, I used `def` to create a witness, so I learned something new:

```
declare[[show_sorts,show_brackets]]
lemma "dom (SOME b. dom b = A) = A"
proof-
def w == "(SOME b::('a => 'b option). dom b = A)"
hence "dom w = A"
  by(metis (lifting, mono_tags) dom_const dom_restrict inf_top_left someI_ex)
  print_facts
thus ?thesis
  by(metis (lifting, full_types) dom_option_map exE_some)
qed
```

But, I try to use a `fix/assume` combination in place `def`, where supposedly `def` is an abbreviation, and I get that mysterious and greatly infuriating message, "Failed to refine any pending goal", which makes me wonder why I want to use this language.

```
declare[[show_sorts,show_brackets]]
lemma "dom (SOME b. dom b = A) = A"
proof-
fix w assume w_def: "w == (SOME b::('a => 'b option). dom b = A)"
hence "dom w = A"
  by(metis (lifting, mono_tags) dom_const dom_restrict inf_top_left someI_ex)
  print_facts
thus ?thesis
oops
```

For the two proofs, when the cursor is at the line before `print_facts`, what I see in the output panel is exactly the same, other than the `def` proof shows `proof (state): step 4`, and the `fix/assume` proofs shows `proof (state): step 5`. The facts at `print_facts` are also the same.

From searches, I know that "Failed to refine any pending goal" has been a source of great pain for many. In the past, I finally figured out the trick to get rid of it for what I was doing, but it doesn't make sense here, not that it made sense to me there either.

**Update 140118_0054**

L.Noschinski gives the subtle tip from [IsaUserList 2012-11-13](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/fa.isabelle/proving%2420existentially%2420quantified%2420statements%2420using%2420%2427obtain%2427ed%2420witness%2420fails|sort%3arelevance|spell%3atrue/fa.isabelle/ZdSGteleBnk/zoeBvuBtBsMJ):

> When you use "fix" or "def" to define a
>   variable, they either get just generalized (i.e. turned into schematics)
>   (fix) or replaced by their right hand side (definitions)
>   when a block is closed / a show is performed.

So for the `fix/assumes` form of the proof, I put part of it in brackets, and for some reason, it exports the fact in the way that's needed:

```
lemma "dom (SOME b. dom b = A) = A"
proof-
{
fix w assume "w == (SOME b::('a => 'b option). dom b = A)"
hence "dom w = A"
  by(metis (lifting, mono_tags) dom_const dom_restrict inf_top_left someI_ex)
}
thus ?thesis
  by(metis (lifting, full_types) dom_option_map exE_some)
qed
```

I go ahead and throw in a `let` form of the proof. I wouldn't have known to use the schematic variable `?w` without having looked at M.Eberl's proofs.

```
lemma "dom (SOME b. dom b = A) = A"
proof-
let ?w = "(SOME b::('a => 'b option). dom b = A)"
have "dom ?w = A"
  by(metis (lifting, mono_tags) dom_const dom_restrict inf_top_left someI_ex)
thus ?thesis
  by(metis (lifting, full_types) dom_option_map exE_some)
qed
```