# Trying to understand fix/assume/show "Failure to refine goal"; Cmd to show proof info for schematic vars

Tags: isabelle

My questions here are a spin-off of what was a tangent in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197612/use-of-obtain-produces-a-fixed-type-variable-warning).

For these questions, I use a very simple lemma, though my second question is fairly involved.

The error *"Local statement fails to refine any pending goal"* is one of the more frustrating errors, when using `show` or `thus` and when all my logic appears correct, so I'm trying to better understand the error message that occurs below at `lemma fix_2`.

I know the fix for it, which is my `lemma fix_1`, but the more I know, the better I might be at dealing with another *"fails to refine any pending goal"*.

Anyone interested might be able to answer Q1 and Q2 just by reading the questions, and then looking at the two lemmas.

There's a lot of information I put in below. I format the comments below like I do to be able to compare how `this` and `goal` change after commands. Doing that, I'm able to get a better understanding of what's happening with the use of `let`, `def`, and `fix/assume`, where the main purpose is to try and understanding the error at the `show` command of `lemma fix_2`.

I don't know how to make a question like this simple.

### Questions

Here, I put forth two questions. You will need to skip down to look at `lemma let_1` and `lemma fix_2`. I tried to use HTML anchors to create links within this page, but it didn't work.

- **Q1:** Below, at `lemma let_1`, I use `print_commands`. I looked through those commands to try to find commands that will give me information about how schematic variables are instantiated. I found `print_binds`, which shows my use of schematic variable `?w`. Are there any other commands that will give me information about what's happening with schematic variables in a proof?
- **Q2**: Am I right in saying the following?

  - At the use of the `show "card {} = 0"` in `lemma fix_2`, the `this` fact and its implicit hypothesis, `card w = 0  [w == {}]`, are used to create a rule similar to what is exported after the `{...}` block in `lemma fix_1`, where the exported rule there is `(?w2 == {}) ==> card ?w2 = 0`.
  - The created rule is then used to do some kind of unification with the proof goal in `show "card {} = 0"`, in which the schematic variable is instantiated with `{}`, but something doesn't match up, and an error occurs.

### The behavior of `def` and `fix/assume` described

The primary context of this question is this statement by L.Noschinski [on the IsaUserList](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/fa.isabelle/proving%2420existentially%2420quantified%2420statements%2420using%2420%2427obtain%2427ed%2420witness%2420fails|sort%3arelevance|spell%3atrue/fa.isabelle/ZdSGteleBnk/zoeBvuBtBsMJ):

> When you use "fix" or "def" to define a variable, they either get just generalized (i.e. turned into schematics) (fix) or replaced by their right hand side (definitions) when a block is closed / a show is performed.

I partially restate it to show how I understand it for the `show` command, where what I say is also based on how `def_1` and `fix_1` behave below, which both use a `{...}` block:

If the statements `def x == "P"` and `fix y assume "y == P"` are used before a `show` command, as in `def_2` and `fix_2` below, at the use of the `show` command, the following will happen:

- For `def x`, any use of `x` in the `this` fact will be replaced by `P`.
- For `fix y`, a rule will be created using both the `this` fact and its implicit hypothesis, such as after the `{...}` in `fix_1` below. In this rule, `y` will be replaced by a schematic variable.

### Five lemmas for studying `this`, `goal`, `have` and `show`

**declares**

I use `show_question_marks` because I need to see when schematic variables are introduced when `fix/assume` is used.

The use of `show_hyps` shows the implicit hypothesis for a proof fact, in square brackets. These implicit conditions get used in an exported rule when `fix/assume` is used.

```
declare[[show_question_marks=true, show_hyps=true]]
declare[[show_sorts=false, show_types=false, show_brackets=false]]
```

**One basic lemma, and 5 variations which have a proof fact not used**

The basic lemma shows what's actually being proved. I then have the following:

- `let_1` to look at how the use of `let` affects `this`.
- `def_1`, which uses `def` and a `{...}` block, to see how `def` behaves and how `this` is exported.
- `def_2`, which has no `{...}` block, to be able to look at `this` before `show` is used.
- `fix_1` and `fix_2`, which are likewise to `def_1` and `def_2`, but use `fix/assume`.

**lemma with no proof fact**

All of the lemmas below are the next lemma, and are proved the same. What the others have in addition is one proof fact which is not needed, and not used by the `show` command.

The purpose of the proof fact is to help me see how `def` and `fix` change the `this` fact when `have` is proved, and see how they export `this` after a block `{...}` is closed.

```
lemma "card {} = (0::nat)"
proof-
show "card {} = 0"
  by(simp)
qed
```

**let_1**

```
lemma let_1: "card {} = (0::nat)"
proof-
let ?w = "{}::'a set"         (*No `this` fact: ?w is instantiated as {}.*)
print_commands
print_binds                   (*term bindings: w? == bot          *)
have "card ?w = (0::nat)"     (*goal: card {} = 0                 *)
  by(simp)                    (*this: card {} = 0                 *)
show "card {} = 0"            (*goal: card {} = 0                 *)
  by(simp)
qed
```

**def_1, {...}**

```
lemma def_1: "card {} = (0::nat)"
proof-
{def w == "{}::'a set"        (*this: w == {}  [w == {}] [name "local.w_def"] *)
  from this 
have "card w = (0::nat)"      (*goal: card w = 0            *)
  by(simp)                    (*this: card w = 0  [w == {}] *)
}                             (*this: card {} = 0           *)
show "card {} = 0"            (*goal: card {} = 0           *)
  by(simp)
qed
```

**def_2, no block**

```
lemma def_2: "card {} = (0::nat)"
proof-
def w == "{}::'a set"         (*this: w == {}  [w == {}] [name "local.w_def"] *)
  from this 
have "card w = (0::nat)"      (*goal: card w = 0            *)
  by(simp)                    (*this: card w = 0  [w == {}] *)
show "card {} = 0"            (*goal: card {} = 0           *)
  by(simp)
qed
```

**fix_1, {...}**

```
lemma fix_1: "card {} = (0::nat)"
proof-
{fix w assume "w == {}::'a set" (*this: w == {}  [w == {}]           *)
  from this 
have "card w = (0::nat)"        (*goal: card w = 0                   *)
  by(simp)                      (*this: card w = 0  [w == {}]        *)
}                               (*this: (?w2 == {}) ==> card ?w2 = 0 *)
show "card {} = 0"              (*goal: card {} = 0                  *)
  by(simp)            
qed
```

**fix_2, no block**

```
lemma fix_2: "card {} = (0::nat)" 
proof-
fix w assume "w == {}::'a set"(*this: w == {}  [w == {}]    *)
  from this 
have "card w = (0::nat)"      (*goal: card w = 0            *)
  by(simp)                    (*this: card w = 0  [w == {}] *)
show "card {} = 0"            (*Local statement fails to refine any pending goal
                                Failed attempt to solve goal by exported rule:
                                (?w3 == {}) ==> card {} = 0 *)
oops
```

## Filling in details for L.Paulson's answer, per my understanding

**140119:**

The answer to Q2 and why the error occurs in `fix_2` is given by L.Paulson when he says,

> In the proof of *`fix_2`*, you have "*`fix w`*". This extends the context with *`w`*. The context no longer matches the original context of the goal...

After having done a search on *"local context"* in [isar-ref.pdf](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/website-Isabelle2013-2/dist/Isabelle2013-2/doc/isar-ref.pdf), I do the gofer work to fill in some details, as I understand them.

The explicit answer to my Q2 is, no, I'm not right, where I'll quote from `isar-ref.pdf` to explain why the formula `(?w3 == {}) ==> card {} = 0` is in the error message.

Another short answer from `isar-ref.pdf` is that `presume` in place of `assume` will *"weaken the local context"* and get rid of the error, because, apparently, the context is no longer extended by `w`, as described by L.Paulson.

**Why the complexity of my example `fix_2`**

My setup for this question was academic, as if a professor said, "In `fix_2`, modify the lemma in a minimal way to get rid of the error, while still using `fix`. In particular, do not use `def`, `obtain`, or `let` to eliminate the error. My use of `{...}`, as in `fix_1`, was an acceptable solution, but I wanted to go further and understand what produces the formula in the error message of `fix_2`, to help me in the future.

My use of `fix/assume` in `fix_2` is specific to the previous question I link to at the top. Here, I introduced a proof fact to ensure an error, like I get there, but here, I don't use the proof fact, to simplify things, so I don't have to use `from this` or `thus`, but only have to use `show`.

In my answer to my previous question, for the lemma at hand, I couldn't see why `def` produced no error when `fix/assume` did. The info in the output panel is almost identical there for `def` and `fix/assume`, and `isar-ref.pdf` describes `def` as an abbreviation for `fix/assume`, page 117, where the key word is "basically":

> Basically, *`def x == t`* abbreviates *`fix x "assume x == t"`*...

**Local context, it' like, not unimportant, which is to say huge**

There was this foggy notion in my mind that somewhere in the answer was the issue of local context, because I've seen the word "context" a lot in the docs. Knowing that is why I threw in the use of `{...}` to fix the problem once I read L.Noschinski's tip, and why I searched on "local context" after L.Paulson's answer.

**Why `(?w3 == {}) ==> card {} = 0` is in the error message, I think**

The explanation is on page 34 of isar-ref.pdf in *2.2.2 Structured statements*:

> A simple statement consists of named propositions. The full form admits local context elements followed by the actual conclusions, such as *`fixes x assumes "A x" shows "B x"`*. The final result emerges as a Pure rule after discharging the context: *`!!x. A x ==> B x`*.

I'm assuming here that `fixe/assume` in a proof works similar to a `fixes/assumes` in a lemma statement.

My first guess, rather than my Q2, was on track. By L.Noschinski, I knew that `w` in `assume "w == {}"` gets changed to a schematic variable when `show` is invoked, so the left-hand side of the error formula, `(?w3 == {}) ==> card {} = 0`, matches up with with the formula of `assume "w == {}"`, and the right-hand side matches up with the formula of `show "card {} = 0"`.

I changed my guess on a bicycle ride, that a rule like `fix_1`'s exported `this` was created, `(?w2 == {}) ==> card ?w2 = 0`, and that `?w2` was instantiated with `{}`. That didn't match very well with `(?w3 == {}) ==> card {} = 0`, but it was all a guess anyway.

**Two more quotes about local context**

Because of my use of `fix/assume`, this next quote put me on the right track, after given the answer by L.Paulson that my `fix/assume` extends the context.

pg.32 in *2.2 The Isar proof language*:

> The remaining elements *`fix`* and *`assume`* build up a local context (see §2.2.1),
>   while *`show`* refines a pending sub-goal by the rule resulting from a nested
>   sub-proof (see §2.2.3).

My pursuit here has largely been about trying to see what's happening under the hood when `show` is used. I'm still pursuing commands to give me some feedback about `show` that's not normally shown in the output panel:

pg.117 in *6.2.4 Goals*:

> *`show a: alpha`* is like *`have a: alpha`* plus a second stage to refine some 
>   pending sub-goal for each one of the finished result...

**Using `presume` in place of `assume`**

Finally, I show another solution to my academic exercise. What I quote below wouldn't have had any meaning to me without L.Paulson's answer that in `fix_2`, I'm extending the context.

pg.120 in *6.3.2 Initial and terminal proof steps*:

> Debugging such a situation might involve temporarily changing *`show`* into *`have`*, 
>   or weakening the local context by replacing occurrences of *`assume`* by *`presume`*.

```
lemma fix_3: "card {} = (0::nat)" 
proof-
fix w presume "w == {}::'a set"(*this: w == {}  [w == {}]   *)
  from this 
have "card w = (0::nat)"      (*goal: card w = 0            *)
  by(simp)                    (*this: card w = 0  [w == {}] *)
show "card {} = 0"            (*goal: card {} = 0           *)
print_binds                   (*term bindings:
                                  ?this == card w = 0
                                  ... == 0
                                  ?thesis == card bot = 0   *)
by(simp)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making something that should be simple very complicated.

In the proof of `fix_2`, you have `fix w`. This extends the context with `w`. The context no longer matches the original context of the goal, hence show `card {} = 0` yields the error message you mention.

Probably the lemma you really need in this proof is `!!w. card w = 0`. When proving this lemma, you will insert `fix w` in a local block, and it will all work.

Comment: Larry, thanks. I wouldn't have understood the formula in the error without understanding the significance of `fix/assume` in regards to the local context. I explain why I made things overly complex, and I added some details to your answer, based on isar-ref.pdf, to try and explain it all to myself.